# Static Parameter List in Crystal Reports 2008

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a static list of user names as a parameter in CR2008.  I want to be able to use CR syntax to add database values to the users selected and query using that.

For instance, if the report runner selects Doe, John from my list of parameters, I need to query the database using something like

```
If {?prmUsers} = "Doe, John" then variableA = "doejoh" And variableB = "john.doe@gmail.com"
```

And the select would be something like:

```
Declare @BeginDate SmallDateTime
Declare @EndDate SmallDateTime
Set @BeginDate = '2009-01-19'
Set @EndDate = '2009-01-23'

SELECT DISTINCT
    DateTime,
    [Recipient-Address],
    [Message-Subject],
    [Sender-Address]
FROM
    dbo.Logs
WHERE
    LEFT([Recipient-Address], 6) IN ( 'doejoh' ) OR
    LEFT([Recipient-Address], 10) IN ( 'john.doe@g' )
    AND DateTime BETWEEN @BeginDate + ' 00:00:00' And @EndDate + ' 23:59:59'
```

Of course, the report runner would be able to select multiple names.  **Any ideas**?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in "canned" Crystal Reports. Your workaround is to create an app that runs your reports. You then could design the prompt to work as you describe above and apply the "final" parameter value to the report.